# Center vertically and in same line - HTML

Tags: css, html

How can we center vertically the second div.

```
<div style="text-align: center;" >  
    <div style=" width:50px; display:inline-block; "><b>This should come in center and</b>  
    </div>  
    <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:initial;"><b>this should be in same line BUT VERTICALLY CENTERED</b>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

Any help will be very appreciated.
Thanks

**Update:-**
Check my fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/linkmanishgupta/8SMLY/

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: @Kermani want to center vertically - the second div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle` for the child divs and add `display:table` and `margin:auto` for parent div.

```
.sub_div1{
  width:50px; display:table-cell; background:grey
}
.sub_div2{
  display:table-cell; background: aqua; vertical-align: middle
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsbin.com/lovetuta/4/)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I also want the both sub div to appear in the center not left aligned. watch this- http://jsfiddle.net/linkmanishgupta/8SMLY/

Comment: Either give parent `div` a css style rule of `width:100%; display:table`. Or Give the parent `div` a fixed width and css rule of `margin:0 auto;`.

Comment: Yup! It worked.. Thanks a lot.
Here is fiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/linkmanishgupta/4W7YP/

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question as well but:

**Please look at this code:**

```
<div style="vertical-align: middle;" >  
    <div style=" width:50px; background:red; display:inline-block;float:left "><b>This should come in center and</b>  
    </div>  
    <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:initial;line-height: 100px;"><b>this should be in same line BUT VERTICALLY CENTERED</b>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kermani/9kav9/1/)

Comment: I want the outer div with its sub div to align in center.. (currently left aligned)

Comment: but the answer that @Sowmya gave you is really better than my answer

Comment: Yes. And this is what I needed. :) Thanks a lot everyone. http://jsfiddle.net/linkmanishgupta/4W7YP/